# I am having a syntax error in relation to pulling row data - postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, row, restore

I just restored a postgres dump into a new database and when i attempt to pull row data I am getting an error message:

command used:

```
SELECT * FROM ops_article;
ERROR: syntax error at or near "/"
LINE 1: /C postgres
```

I do not see any / located in line of of my sql database.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Show us your "attempt to pull row data" and maybe a sample of the table(s) involved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you did this:

```
/C postgres
SELECT * FROM ops_article;
```

The correct syntax is \c postgres which will execute and then let you run the next statement.